# Android-Audio Recording

Tags: android, audio, audio-player

I would like to know

1. The Audio Recording can be done within emulator
2. It should be stored in some other place but not in SD card.

Answer (score 1):

1. no
2. that question is part of your other question... double post!
3. please try to search first....

Comment: thank you ,will you say whether audio recording can be done within emulator if not is there any other option