# audio recording

Tags: android

Is it possible for audio recording in emulator and store it not in sdk but some where else

Comment: didn't you post the same question yesterday already?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493673/android-audio-recording

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can record the audio with Emulator. But for that you have to give the hardware ability to record the audio in to the avd hardware setting.

See the below image of the avd properties from avd manager.

[image]

Here, from the avd manager you can add the hardware cability with the whatever you want but it will work only if you have attached hardware with that.

So for recording of sound if you have attached the MIC then only it will work. Otherwise it will raise error or exception that hardware not found.

Enjoy. :))

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot record audio using the emulator.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html
"Note that the emulator doesn't have hardware to capture audio or video, but actual mobile devices are likely to provide these capabilities, accessible through the MediaRecorder class"